# When to use that's and when to use it's?

Tags: american-english, british-english

I feel am not good with using that's and it's in a sentence. Can anyone please help me, when to use the former one and when the latter?

For example, what will come here, that's the least I could do for you or it's the least I could do for you.

I just don't understand the difference.

Are these two different in british and american english?

Comment: "Thank you for [your help]." -  "Don't mention it, it was the least I could do." _It_ refers to the service just mentioned. _That_ just gives more emphasis - "That was something your sister should have done for you."

Answer (score 1):

*That's* and *it's* are contractions of *that is* and *it is*.

You are able to tell yourself which sounds best if you expand them as such. One will flow while the other may make a clanking sound.

Either may be used in most cases with little difference.
The purist may say that the *that* refers objectively to that which has been done, as a thing or object. Using *it* will be more in hand in the present.